# Django jquery datatable "aData is undefined" error

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, datatable

I try to implement jquery datatable ajax-source usage in Django however have some problems.
The ajax call is working great and get the response however after that `aData is undefined` error is raised in javascript.

What would be the problem ?

These are what I have so far.

**views.py**

```
def model_history(request):
    o = Model.objects.get(id=request.GET["pk"])
    items_list = list(o.lastupdate_set.all().values())
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(items_list),'application/json')
```

**js**

```
    function viewModelHistory(pk){
        url1 = "/model/history/?pk="+pk;

        $('#history').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": url1,
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
              $.ajax( {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
              } );
            }
          } );
}
```

**listmodel.html**

```
<table id="history">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>col1</th>
                            <th>col2</th>
                            <th>col3</th>
                            <th>col4</th>
                            <th>col5</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: What does `fnCallback` do and what parameters does it expect?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have an issue with the format of your JSON structure. jquery.datatables expects it to look something like

`{"aaData": [["blah1", "blah2", "blah3"]]}`

If your JSON looks like

`[["blah1", "blah2", "blah3"]]`

In your view.py you need to wrap your item_list in a dictionary like so:

```
items_list_dict = {}
items_list_dict.update({'aaData': items_list})
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(items_list_dict),'application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to post your JSON output, but I assume it looks like this:

```
[["key":"val"],["key":"val"]]
```

if so you need to remove your keys from the json. Datatables expects json like this:

```
[["val"],["val"]]
```

One thing you can do is make a list of list from your query

```
my_json = []
for item_list in items_list:
    a = [item_list.xxx_column_name_xxx]
    my_json.append(a)

items_list_dict = {}
items_list_dict.update({'aaData': my_json})
data = json.dumps(items_list_dict)

return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```